# Bug with TableDiff in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables on different sql server instances but with same structure(same names and same data types). each table has 10M rows.Instance A as the base, instance B as the destination.

They should have same data, but actually not. so I use tablediff to generate script for the different rows, then run it on the destination B.

It generates about 200 scripts,each script has 3000 statements. and I find one strange thing, sometimes it has deleting script first, and then inserting script for same record. and I have compared the row on 2 instances, they actually do have the same record.

So my question is, why it has this kind of behavior?why it could not skip this kind of compare?

Comment: Actually this is not a bug

Comment: @El.Ham if it is not a bug, then why it generated the script like that pattern?